# How to clone scope in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data as follow:

```
$scope.form= response.data.shooter;
oldData= response.data.shooter;
```

I have an issue in here:

Both have the same object array.

When I delete any value from `oldData`, it is also getting removed from `$scope.form`.

The code is as follows:

```
$.each(oldData, function(i, e) {
  console.log(oldData[e], $scope.form[e]);
  oldData[e] = '';
  console.log(oldData[e], $scope.form[e]);
});
```

I have searched regarding this, but no luck.

Can anyone tell me, how to create a replica of scope to handle it separately regardless of sync between two array objects i.e. independent replica of scope so that if I make changes in that replica should not affect in scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
$scope.form= response.data.shooter;
oldData= angular.copy(response.data.shooter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `angular.copy` .For copy the object to other.

**angular.copy(source, [destination]);**

`oldData = angular.copy($scope.form);`

`angular.copy($scope.leader, oldData);`

both you can use

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

also you can have a look at `lodash and underscore`

This library provide very nice to method .

Answer (score 0):

Well @Charlietfl is correct I would just like to add some explanation to the issue and solution

Using `=` , you're actually assigning reference of `response.data.shooter` to both `$scope.form` and `oldData` and as reference is the same `updating` one would affect the other (same concept as `shallowCopy` in `C++`). To avoid these kind of issues you need to make `deep copies` of the objects and the way to do that in angular is [**angular.copy()**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)